# ListFragment in Android extends another class

Tags: android, android-fragments

My activity extends another custom class but I need to use ListFragment.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Its something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412759/extend-activity-and-activitygroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the custom class extend ListFragment.

Comment: see, all my activities extends this class, if I should extend another activity from simple fragment what to do?

Comment: I'm guessing your custom class extends Fragment? Copy your custom class, call it listcustomclass and have it extends ListFragment, so when you need a listfragment, extend it from listcustomclass